# Unable to Locate an Element using xpath for live updating fields

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Every time the request id changes on selecting a live update field.

Am trying to get the request id through the xpath

This is the source code.

```
<form id="itemscreen334-33504-" class="itemscreen addMode v_334 ajaxForm form-initialized" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" requestid="18310" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
```

Java Code:

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[Class='itemscreen addMode v_334 ajaxForm form-initialized')]"));
System.out.println("form-->" + form);
String requestNo = form.getAttribute("requestid");
System.out.println("requestNo----------->" + requestNo);
```

Selenium Error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector
>   //form[Class='itemscreen addMode v_334 ajaxForm form-initialized')] is
>   either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error
>   occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the
>   xpath expression //form[Class='itemscreen addMode v_334 ajaxForm
>   form-initialized')] because of the following error: [Exception... "The
>   expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult:
>   "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: ""]

How can i get the request id using xpath?

Comment: One issue in your XPath is that you have `form[Class` instead of `form[@class` but you are better of using a CSS selector as in the answer below. It's more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are providing wrong `xpath`, your `xpath` expression is looks like `cssSelector`, Try as below :-

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form.itemscreen.addMode.v_334.ajaxForm.form-initialized"));
String requestNo = form.getAttribute("requestid");
System.out.println("requestNo----------->" + requestNo);
```

Or if you want to use `xpath` try as below with correct `xpath` :-

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@class = 'itemscreen addMode v_334 ajaxForm form-initialized']"));
String requestNo = form.getAttribute("requestid");
System.out.println("requestNo----------->" + requestNo);
```

**Note** :-if you want partial match with `class` attribute, you should use `xpath` as `By.xpath("//form[contains(@class, 'itemscreen addMode')]")` and `cssSelector` as `By.cssSelector("form.itemscreen.addMode")`

Comment: I have used this css selector for 'Save' button

By.cssSelector("button[type='submit'][data-name = 'Save']") 

i was able to locate it

Why its not working for form type when we give in this format

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[data-name = 'Organization Type']"));

Comment: Not for this case. Its a sample one.
when i tried to use it in similar way, its not able to locate. Is it specific format that we should give it like "form.itemscreen.addMode.v_334.ajaxForm.form-initialized"
?

Comment: @Pradeeba What do you want actually??? your question is about getting attribute `requestid` from `form` element

Comment: If you want to locate form element why are you providing `select`... It should be like `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form[data-name = 'Organization Type']"));`..but as Provided HTML i can't see `data-name` attribute in the form

Comment: Yes. But i need to check on the syntax for using css selector. can we use it in both ways cssSelector("form [class='itemscreen addMode v_334 ajaxForm form-initialized']") as well as cssSelector("form.itemscreen.addMode.v_334.ajaxForm.form-initialized"))

Comment: Yes you can use both.. but in the first case if your order for class name change during run time as like `itemscreen v_334 addMode  ajaxForm form-initialized` then first case will not work while second will work...

Comment: @Pradeeba So I'm suggestting you always prefer second way of `cssSelector` like  `By.cssSelector("form.itemscreen.addMode.v_334.ajaxForm.form-initialized")`...thanks

Comment: @Pradeeba you welcome. Glad to help you.. please accept the answer if it helped...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.....:)